# Error MSB4019 with visual studio for Mac

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac

With visual studio for Mac

> /Users/piyushbhatt/Projects/myfmf/FMF/FMF.Web/fmf.Web.csproj(3,3):
>   Error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (FindMeFood.Web)

Answer (score 14):

You can copy the WebApplications folder from
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0 to v15.0 to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For reference Shine's answer works for future versions of Mono as well.

Just navigate to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/

Here will be a list of versions. Your error message will say which version is missing web targets. In this case it's v15.0. In my case it was v17.0 In any case, open the previous version and copy only the folder "WebApplications" and paste it in the folder for the version that you are having the error for.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug fixed in Mono 5.0.1 release,

https://github.com/xmcclure/website/blob/1ea729c37c407aa6ec19ceef3b02f6969667ae3c/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.1.md

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be missing from the mono5 package.  Report the bug

@https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

I tried to copy the files manually from the 14 folder, but ended up running into other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this [exact same issue for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850865/where-can-i-find-and-install-the-visual-studio-2022-build-tools-for-mac) without realizing this thread is already resolved when I open my question.  Where the only delta is that I am using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac v17.5.2 (build 14) and Mongo project for Visual Studio for Mac 6.12.0 Stable (6.12.0.182).

It turns out that you don't need to hunt down any additional installer, because the WebApplication runtime hasn't changed over the last few years. Just follow @fwan [answer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72818631/1655863).  That resolved my issue.

Below you can also see the md5 sum of the file is exactly identical.

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio

MD5 (./v10.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v11.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v12.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v14.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v16.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v17.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
MD5 (./v9.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets) = 3c0175c55c0a28ddbfc9cce04971fd8a
```